# JPA criteria defined on primary key does not work

Tags: jpa, query-builder, criteria-api

I have an Entity which uses 'Id' and 'updatedDate' as composite primary key. When I build a query with any of these 2 attributes, I get the below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [id] against path

**My query**

```
      @Override
      public MyEntityInterface find(final Long Id) {
      final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
      final CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(this.entityClass);
      final Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(this.entityClass);
      query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(MyEntity.ID_FIELD), Id));
      query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(MyEntity.UPDATED_DATE_FIELD)));
      try {
          return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
      } catch (final NoResultException e) {
          return null;
      }
```

**My Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_sample_table")
@IdClass(MyEntityKey.class)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable, MyEntityInterface,EntityCopySupport<MyEntityInterface> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String ID_FIELD = "id";
public static final String UPDATED_DATE_FIELD = "updatedDate";
public static final String UPDATED_BY_FIELD = "updatedBy";

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Id
@Column(name = "updated_date", nullable=false)
private Date updatedDate;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "updated_by")
private String updatedBy;

@PrePersist
public void updateDate () {
    updatedDate = new Date();
}

@Override
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public Date getUpdatedDate() {
    return this.updatedDate;
}

@Override
public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String getUpdatedBy() {
    return this.updatedBy;
}

@Override
public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

@Override
public void copy(MyEntityInterface source) {
    this.setId(source.getId());
    this.setName(source.getName());
    this.setUpdatedBy(source.getUpdatedBy());
}
```

}

**My Id Class:**

```
public class MyEntityKey implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private Date updatedDate;

public MyEntityKey() {}

public MyEntityKey(Long id, Date updatedDate) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Date getUpdatedDate() {
    return updatedDate;
}
public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((updatedDate == null) ? 0 : updatedDate.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MyEntityKey other = (MyEntityKey) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (updatedDate == null) {
        if (other.updatedDate != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!updatedDate.equals(other.updatedDate))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

When my query criteria is modified to ignore the 'Id' and 'updatedDate' attributes, it works fine -  below is the query that works fine

```
          @Override
          public MyEntityInterface find(final Long Id) {
          final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
          final CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(this.entityClass);
          final Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(this.entityClass);
          query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(MyEntity.UPDATED_BY_FIELD), "user"));
          try {
              return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
          } catch (final NoResultException e) {
              return null;
          }
```

And hardcoding the query as such works fine too as given below:

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT entity FROM MyEntity entity WHERE entity.id = ? ORDER BY entity.updatedDate DESC");
    query.setParameter(1, Id);
    return (MyEntity) query.setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

I have tried to look around the site for this issue but the solution provided in the other posts are more specific to the question asked. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: does your id class have a construtor accepting those two arguments?

Comment: No. It does not have a constructor. Is it required? I referred to the IdClass example as given here http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_

Comment: Tried having constructors in the id class and still no luck - updated the question with the same